# Show IE Favorites using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, hta

I'm writing an HTA and I have a button that I want to open IE and show the users bookmarks.  Is there a good way to go about doing this?  using IE9.

Comment: New site needed: ihavenottriedanythingyetsinceihavenocluewheretobegin.com

Comment: @mplungjan: Do one has it yet, quick, buy it!

Comment: ;) @Rocket - except I rarely need to invoke it

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/17410.asp

```
var  objShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
var objWshFavorite = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Favorites");
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156616.aspx

http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/scripting-vb-script/t-browse-each-site-in-ie-favorites-list-131320.html